trigger an action when a specific field is changed in Django models
I needs to change the OTP_expire value
whenever OTP field change it's value

class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(blank=True)


    OTP = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    OTP_expire = models.DateTimeField(null=True)


For that I thought of creating a trigger, but I could not figure out how to identify if the OTP field has changed or if another field has changed.

Since they are both fields on the same model, you can override the model save() method. Read the documentation carefully. In particular note the caveat about creating or updating models in bulk bypassing save(). So, don't, or not when it matters.
The overhead of updating OPT_expire every time the model is saved is unlikely to be significant, since there's a DB transaction to perform a save happening anyway. But if computing that OTP_expire value is  demanding, you could further record that the OTP value has been changed by replacing that field by a property. You would rename the field, migrate, then install the property, and finally deal with any querysets which filter on the renamed field because they can't filter on a property.
@property
def OTP(self):
    return self.otp   # the actual renamed DB field
@OTP.setter
def OTP(self, value)
    self.otp = value
    self.otp_changed = True

Now in your save method,
    if getattr( self, 'otp_changed', False):
         # yes it has been changed, so reset self.otp
         self.otp = something_complicated()
         # and note the documentation on the save method
         update_fields = {"otp"}.union(update_fields)

